# C# - Find specific folders

Tags: c#, foreach, directory

I'd like to get directories with specific file names:

```
foreach (string subdirTrans in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
```

For instance GetDirectories Where path/Dir1, path/Dir2 etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code so we can help you where you're having problems

Comment: does `Dir1` and `Dir2` have something in common? is there a pattern in the naming?. This would be good to know if you want to avoid an if-clause for every sub-directory.

Comment: I just want to access to these specific directories for instance pathDirectory/Directory1 and pathDirectory/Directory2

Comment: if you know the directory in advance, why don't you simple use the path?

Comment: Try following : string[] paths = { "Directory1", "Directory1", "test_dir" };
            string[] subdirTrans = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\temp").Where(x => paths.Contains(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1))).ToArray();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it:

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath).Where(filePath => list.Any(path => filePath.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
```

with:  `List<string> list = new List<string>();`

Thank you for answering me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 var names = new string[] { "Dir1", "Dir2" };
    var directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("path", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(d => names.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(d)))
        .ToList();
```